# Run simple react js in browser locally

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I am just trying to run a simplest react js file in my browser.  But I am unable to

Please note that I do not want to create-react-app, I just want to try it on my local system.

I did following

1. in my `/Users/me/reactwork`, I created 2 files **clock.html** and **clock.js**
2. then in Chrome browser, I enter `/Users/me/reactwork/clock.html`.  I expect to see my clock but I dont

What I am doing wrong?

I am very new to js and react, just started reading so please provide me step by step instructions.

Here are my files

**clock.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="clock.js">

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**clock.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function tick() {
    const element = (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
            <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
        </div>
    );

    ReactDOM.render(
        element,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
}

setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

Chrome Developer Tools shows this error

```
Failed to load file:///Users/me/reactwork/clock.js: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

I reasearched this error and found that I need server so I issued following command from the location where my html and js files are

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

this starts a server on port 8000, then I went to Chrome and typed

```
http://localhost:8000/clock.html
```

, but this shows error in Chrome Dev Tools

```
clock.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at <anonymous>:3:14
    at n (https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js:12:27049)
    at r (https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js:12:27558)
    at e.src.i.(anonymous function).error (https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js:12:27873)
    at XMLHttpRequest.i.onreadystatechange (https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js:12:27316)
```

**UPDATE**
I gave up trying to make it work as react page suggests on this link to try it on your own using the "Try React" and use my own text editor (`https://reactjs.org/docs/installation.html`).  That did not work as I explained in my post above.

Although I wish I could get it work this way, I was not able, so I then decided to do it as the "Create New App" tab section, then modified index.js file to use the code I had in my clock.js file as described above.  That worked.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

At the very least, you will need to load React (and ReactDOM) in `clock.html`.  Some instructions are available in the [React installation docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/installation.html#using-a-cdn).

If you want to get started quick, an easier option might be to use [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app).  You just need to install [node + npm](https://nodejs.org/) and then run the few commands listed in the create-react-app README:

```
npm install -g create-react-app

create-react-app my-app
cd my-app/
npm start
```

That will create a simple "Hello, world" app and open it in your browser.  Then you can make changes to it and see it update in the browser in real time.

Comment: I updated my html file as above.  What I am missing now?  Thanks

Comment: Thanks man, I gave up on trying to run it on my own, instead went this way and edited created index.js file to display my clock.  That worked

Comment: that seems like an overkill (you'd have to create an entire app every time you develop a new component). you can use other tools that integrate with your existing code, to make the development process seamless (see [my answer on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57239953/547020)).

Comment: Why are people downvoting my answer 2 years later?! ‍♂️  The author of the question said "I am very new to js and react".  This is a simple and reliable way for novice developers to get started with React.  That's the whole point of the project ‍♂️

Comment: This answer is not bad it just doesn't fully answer @pixel question.  create-react-app is an easy option, but pixel needs to know that he/she will not be able to open the file using the path: /Users/me/reactwork/index.html.  CRA is a good option, and so is a tool like Live Server: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer.  If you use VS Code you can add this extension, right click your index.html file and click 'Open with Live Server' and boom you have what you need.

Answer (score 41):

You can run react.js directly into your browser **NPM** or **NODE.JS** are **NOT REQUIRED**.
Here is a snippet:

```js
// main.js

/* You don't need these imports
**  import React from 'react';
**  import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
*/
// React and ReactDOM are already imported in you HTML
// Also import / require are NodeJS thing that doesn't exist in a browser


function tick() {
  const element = (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
    </div>
  );
  ReactDOM.render(
    element,
    document.getElementById('the_root_of_your_reactJS_component')
  );
}

setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->


<body>

  <!-- some HTML -->
  <div id="the_root_of_your_reactJS_component"></div>
  <!-- some other HTML -->
  
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  <!-- babel is required in order to parse JSX -->

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <!-- import react.js -->

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"> </script>
  <!-- import react-dom.js -->

  <script type="text/babel" src="main.js"></script>
  <!-- import your JS and add - type="text/babel" - otherwise babel wont parse it -->
</body>
```

Comment: Note that babel-standalone package is deprecated, so if you want to take advantage of latest features you should use @babel/standalone instead, for example unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.12.4/babel.min.js

Comment: Nedko your answer is not really helpful.  @pixel is already doing what you are suggesting in your code, but is seeing an error message about protocol schemes when trying to open the index.html file.  The best solution is to use a tool like Live Server: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer

Comment: @SpencerPowell My answer illustrates how to run ReacJS locally without using create-react-app  meaning without installing node.js on your local environment. When you click "Run code snippet"  a hello world react code is run. The FE of StackOverflow is not built in React. The accepted answer does not answer the question.

Comment: I agree that the accepted answer does not answer the question either

Comment: Your answer is not bad.  It is somewhat helpful, but it just doesn't address the error he was seeing when trying to run it the way you describe above (namely the protocol scheme errors he/she was seeing).

Comment: @SpencerPowell, please read the comments in the code snippet. He is trying to use require in the browser by `import React from 'react';` which babel transpile to `var React = require('react')` and this is how you would require modules in NodeJS. In the browser **require is not defined**

Answer (score 1):

First of all your html file has some wrong syntax. `head` tag is used for non visual elements. You need to add that `h1` tag inside a `body` tag. If your knowledge on html is not that good I suggest you to get a little familiar with HTML and Javascript before diving into React.

Second problem is that you are missing required react scripts in your html. You need to add react and required javascript libraries to your file before using react. You can find more information about that [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/installation.html)

The third problem I can see is that you are missing a tag with id `root` in your html. Line with `document.getElementById('root')` trying to find an element with the id root in your html to render react element inside.

I suggest you to check [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/) for quick and easy way to learn basic [HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) and [Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) if you are not familiar with. After that you can start learning React with official tool create-react-app. This will help you to understand project structure and how things work better.

Comment: I updated my html file like above but I still dont see any output?  Thanks

Comment: Source of your script is at the wrong place for beginning. It should be `<script src="clock.js" ...></script>`

Comment: I moved it and updated as above but still see no output?  thanks

Comment: You are not importing any react libraries in your code. I would strongly suggest you to read a little bit more about html javascript and react before diving into code because nobody can help you step by step here like this.

Comment: I am doing that, in fact, using your link (https://reactjs.org/docs/installation.html) I downloaded the html file that should work from react site and replaced my original html file.  I am not sure why you say I am int importing any react libraries, they are imported in the html above, the 3 lines pointing to .js libraries are as provided by react page.  Thanks

Comment: To use `ReactDOM` in your code you need to do `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'` https://reactjs.org/docs/installation.html#hello-world-with-es6-and-jsx

Comment: I imported that too and updated the original post as above but I still see nothing displayed in any browser (Sarary, FF, Chrome)

Comment: remove interval and tick function and just try rendering first. see if you are gonna see any error on developer console.

Comment: I updated to add error Chrome DevTools show me above at the bottom.  Thanks again

Comment: Error is pretty self explanatory. do some research on that.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to open the file using the path: /Users/me/reactwork/index.html.  Unfortunately the React docs don't mention this nor do they point you in the right direction.

The best solution is to use a tool like Live Server: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer.

If you use VS Code you can add this extension, right click your index.html file and click 'Open with Live Server' and boom you have what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The answer below worked for me.

Basically, the solution is to include the export file and the import file in the index.html file, each in a SCRIPT element.

Additionally, they  must have the custom attribute data-plugins="transform-es2015-modules-umd" along with the expected attribute type="text/babel"

Like that:

```
<script data-plugins="transform-es2015-modules-umd" type="text/babel" src="./MyExport.js"></script>

<script data-plugins="transform-es2015-modules-umd" type="text/babel" src="./MyImport.js"></script>
```

The order is important. The script importing the module should be put last in the index.html

[Source]
[How to perform import/export in client-side React JSX using Babel-Standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53972473/how-to-perform-import-export-in-client-side-react-jsx-using-babel-standalone)

Answer (score 0):

You need local web server to run your JS locally.

Answer (score -1):

You can now audit a single component live, during development, with ***[styleguidist](https://react-styleguidist.js.org/)***.

It's a tool designed for the purpose of sharing design knowledge among engineering and design teams, and it acts as a "kitchensink" or "showcase" for live components.

While somewhat similar to *[storybook](https://storybook.js.org/)*, it's prefareable to it for development purposes, as *storybook* will only render static states of components (akin to the *storyboard* in film production).

It's mentioned in the *create-react-app* documentation on *[developing components in isolation](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/developing-components-in-isolation#getting-started-with-styleguidist)*.