# How can I convert JSX to JS without npm using a build script?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have an application that consists of an html file like so:

```
<!-- ... existing HTML ... -->

<div id="input-field"></div>

<!-- ... existing HTML ... -->

  <!-- Load React. -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

  <!-- Load our React component. -->
  <script src="InputField.js"></script>
</body>
```

I also have a react component that looks like this:

```
class InputField extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>test</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<InputField />, document.getElementById('input-field'))
```

As you may have noticed, the react component is using jsx syntax. I want to be able to run a build script that converts all my jsx files to js so that my browser can read and render the components.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run simple react js in browser locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46506332/run-simple-react-js-in-browser-locally)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to add `Babel` to transpile your `JSX` which here is how you would do that by adding this line to your `html` file:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
```

and then you need is to add the `type` property to your `InputField` script like this:

```
<script type="text/babel" src="InputField.js"></script>
```

Here is the complete code:

```
<!-- ... existing HTML ... -->

<div id="like_button_container"></div>

<!-- ... existing HTML ... -->

  <!-- Load React. -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <!-- Babel js -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>


  <!-- Load our React component. -->
  <script type="text/babel" src="InputField.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: @user18941960 thats... thats the point of the npm build script

Comment: @user18941960 that will only happen when running it locally in development. once you create a build it's stripped out.