# import & require both are not working for my JavaScript file. Shows some error

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, visual-studio-code, babeljs

I am trying to make a simple webpage using React.

Here is the `index.html` file for the same:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="index.js" type="module"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

And here is it's `index.js` file:

```
const Header = require("./Header.mjs")
const MainComponent = require("./MainComponent.mjs")
const Footer = require("./Footer.mjs")

function CustomPageComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <MainComponent />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<CustomPageComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

The required files that I want to render are Header, MainComponent and Footer which are as given below:

`Header.mjs`

```
// import React from "react"

export default function Header() {
    return (
        <div>
      <header>
        <nav className="nav">
          <img
            src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/React-icon.svg/1280px-React-icon.svg.png"
            className = "nav-logo"
          />
          <ul className="nav-items">
            <li>Pricing</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
      </div>
    );
}
```

And same goes for Footer and MainComponent...

But when I run `index.js` in the VSCode terminal, in the output screen, I get the following error:

```
[Running] node "c:\Users\epsit\Desktop\firstreact\index.js"
c:\Users\epsit\Desktop\firstreact\index.js:7
    <div>
    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1176:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.14.2

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.139 seconds
```

I made a `.babelrc` file too but it didn;t help either. I have tried using both `import` and `require` approaches in order to get my code running.

Any solutions for it? Is the error showing up due to some trivial syntax error or there is something else which I am missing out? Please check it out!

Comment: try renaming file to use ".jsx" file extension?

Comment: i tried renaming them with .jsx extension too but still, when i ran the code, blank page appeared.

Comment: Running `node "c:\Users\epsit\Desktop\firstreact\index.js"` would not work. You are practically trying to run index.js as a node script. You can check here on how to run Reactjs locally https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46506332/run-simple-react-js-in-browser-locally

Comment: well... I also tried to run the respective ```index.html``` file also, but the output is completely blank still. So....?